# Fedora 22 4.1.3 Inspiron 13 7000 Touchpad Not Responding

Tags: fedora, touchpad

Recently updated my Fedora 22 installation on my Inspiron 13 7000 laptop and the touchpad stopped working, even after many boots which seems to fix the problem a lot.

I used `evtest` to see if the devices were receiving input and they weren't.

Results from `xinput` is:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen Pen                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL0675:00 06CB:75DB UNKNOWN              id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by running `grub2-mkconfig` and rebooting.

I can only assume this corrected the loading of the modules when booting.